# Android use android.graphics.Matrix in Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, matrix

Is there a way I can use **android.graphics.Matrix** in local Unit test for Android. When I try using the matrix object I get the error message: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getValues in android.graphics.Matrix not mocked.**

I suspect that since the Matrix class uses native methos, that means the class cannot be used in local unit test. So in order to use it I have to create a mock object using for example Mockito. Here is an example of creating a mock object, that always returns the identity matrix.

```
    /**
     * Create Mockito graphic matrix, since the matrix methods are native and are not supported
     * in local unit testing. We need to use Mockito to mock a matrix, that always return the
     * identity matrix, when getValues() method is called. Identity matrix is the default matrix 
     * with no transformations applied to it.
     */
    fun getMockMatrix(): Matrix {

        val mockMatrix = mock(Matrix::class.java)
        doAnswer { invocation ->

            val v = (invocation.arguments[0] as FloatArray)

            // always set values to match the identity matrix, when getValues() method is called
            v[0] = 1f
            v[4] = 1f
            v[8] = 1f

            null
        }.`when`(mockMatrix).getValues(FloatArray(9))

        val matrixValues = FloatArray(9)
        mockMatrix.getValues(matrixValues)

        // check if the mocked matrix matches the identity matrix
        assertArrayEquals(
            matrixValues, floatArrayOf(
                1f, 0f, 0f,
                0f, 1f, 0f,
                0f, 0f, 1f
            )
        )
        return mockMatrix
    }
```

That work well in some cases for example when I need to use it as dummy object, but when I need to do actual transformations with it or map point there is no way to achieve it using mock object.

Now I made my test using `Instrumented Test`, since it uses the Emulator and that way it have access to native methods integrated in Android OS, but those type of tests are way slower than local unit tests. My question is if there is way to create local unit test that makes the use of the Matrix class available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [Robolectric](https://robolectric.org/). It would provide a `Matrix` implementation that can run on a local JVM, so you won't have to use your own mocks. The downside of using Robolectric is that you're testing against Robolectric's implementation of the Android SDK, which may or may not be consistent with the actual code that runs on an actual device. That said, Robolectric has been around for a while and is maintained by Google, so it should be safe to use.
2. Abstract `Matrix` away from your code. Mocking types you don't own is not a good practice in general, as you'd inevitably be making assumptions about that type's implementation which may or may not hold when you're running against the actual implementation. Creating test doubles for your own types is safe, as you're in control of the behavior. Creating a thin wrapper over `Matrix` that you can mock/fake in your tests and which itself does not require unit tests is the solution I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with native method use within the framework class. The same occurs when you use any Android framework class. For example I had the same problem with `android.graphics.Point`. It's a very basic class that just contains an x and a y coordinate, but can't be used in unit tests.

What we can do in this case is create our own version of that class that will be used in unit tests only. So under your test directory tree, just create the class `android.graphics.Matrix` (with the same exact fully-qualified class name) and create a dummy implementation (or just copy it from [the Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Matrix.java) - not sure how it will work with native code though). That version of the class will then be used by both your unit test code and your actual main branch code while the unit test is running. But as it only exists in the test directory tree, it won't be used when your actual app is running.